# Issue with library installations through pip

Tags: python, virtualenv

I have a new M1 Pro Mac and I'm trying to set up my dev environment. My Mac defaults to python2 still, so I have to reference python 3 as `$ python3` in the terminal

I know Python comes with a preinstalled module to install pip for you, so I ran the following.

```
python3 -m ensurepip --upgrade
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Looking in links: /var/folders/c8/cfg93ngn5lv63xqptw_mg8bm0000gn/T/tmp8m1wvvzr
Requirement already up-to-date: setuptools in /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages (49.2.1)
Requirement already up-to-date: pip in /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages (20.2.3)
danielschnoll@Daniels-MBP ~ % python3 pip
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/python3: can't open file 'pip': [Errno 2] No such file or directory'
danielschnoll@Daniels-MBP ~ % pip
zsh: command not found: pip
danielschnoll@Daniels-MBP ~ % pip3

Usage.....
```

I then made sure pip was upgraded

```
danielschnoll@Daniels-MBP ~ % python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Collecting pip
  Downloading pip-22.0.4-py3-none-any.whl (2.1 MB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 2.1 MB 3.0 MB/s 
Installing collected packages: pip
  WARNING: The scripts pip, pip3 and pip3.8 are installed in '/Users/danielschnoll/Library/Python/3.8/bin' which is not on PATH.
  Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location.
  NOTE: The current PATH contains path(s) starting with `~`, which may not be expanded by all applications.
Successfully installed pip-22.0.4
```

pip still doesn't work if I do `$ pip` it needs `$ pip3`. Not a big deal. But now I want to install Flask so I can do some API development.

```
danielschnoll@Daniels-MBP ~ % pip3 install flask
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Collecting flask
  Downloading Flask-2.0.3-py3-none-any.whl (95 kB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 95.6/95.6 KB 1.9 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Collecting Jinja2>=3.0
  Downloading Jinja2-3.0.3-py3-none-any.whl (133 kB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 133.6/133.6 KB 2.9 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Collecting click>=7.1.2
  Downloading click-8.0.4-py3-none-any.whl (97 kB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 97.5/97.5 KB 3.6 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Collecting Werkzeug>=2.0
  Downloading Werkzeug-2.0.3-py3-none-any.whl (289 kB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 289.2/289.2 KB 6.2 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Collecting itsdangerous>=2.0
  Downloading itsdangerous-2.1.0-py3-none-any.whl (15 kB)
Collecting MarkupSafe>=2.0
  Downloading MarkupSafe-2.1.0-cp38-cp38-macosx_10_9_universal2.whl (17 kB)
Installing collected packages: Werkzeug, MarkupSafe, itsdangerous, click, Jinja2, flask
  WARNING: The script flask is installed in '/Users/danielschnoll/Library/Python/3.8/bin' which is not on PATH.
  Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location.
  NOTE: The current PATH contains path(s) starting with `~`, which may not be expanded by all applications.
Successfully installed Jinja2-3.0.3 MarkupSafe-2.1.0 Werkzeug-2.0.3 click-8.0.4 flask-2.0.3 itsdangerous-2.1.0
```

Good, Flask is installed, and I see it if I do `$ pip3 list`

```
danielschnoll@Daniels-MBP ~ % pip3 list
Package      Version
------------ -------
autopep8     1.6.0
click        8.0.4
Flask        2.0.3
itsdangerous 2.1.0
Jinja2       3.0.3
MarkupSafe   2.1.0
pip          22.0.4
pycodestyle  2.8.0
setuptools   49.2.1
six          1.15.0
toml         0.10.2
Werkzeug     2.0.3
wheel        0.33.1
```

But in my python code, I can't import Flask. My pylinter throws errors saying Flask isn't findable. Sure enough if I launch the terminal and open the Python3 interpreter, this happens

```
danielschnoll@Daniels-MBP ~ % python3
Python 3.8.9 (default, Oct 26 2021, 07:25:53) 
[Clang 13.0.0 (clang-1300.0.29.30)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from Flask import flask
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Flask'
>>>
```

Looking back at my installation journey, I found the following

```
WARNING: The script flask is installed in '/Users/danielschnoll/Library/Python/3.8/bin' which is not on PATH.
```

Well, it is. I added it manually to my `.bash_profile`

```
export PATH="$PATH:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin"
```

Same with my `.bashrc`

```
export PATH="$PATH:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin"
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/share/dotnet/dotnet
```

What is going on here?? Can someone please assist? Thanks

Comment: script = things you can run from command line, cli utilities. Paths for importable libraries are defined in `PYTHONPATH`